# Primefaces - Loading Images in Mobile Version

Tags: java, primefaces, facelets

I have a little problem with loading Image in Primefaces 5.2 - in standard version this works perfectly, but in mobile (without special addons) does not... The fileUploadListener is not even executed:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{imageUploader.uploadImageAfter}"
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG)$/"
              mode="advanced" auto="true" />
```

Java method which is not executed (contains some LOGGERS inside):

```
public void uploadImageAfter(FileUploadEvent event) {...}
```

PS. I know there's solution on Primefaces Main Website, but I also heard that this should work too